# Find the global extrema of $f(x,y)=\sin(xy)$ on $D=[(x,y)| x = [0,\pi], y=[0,1]]$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Find the absolute maximum and absolute minimum of the function:

$$f(x,y) = \sin(xy) \text{ on } D=[(x,y)| x = [0,\pi], y=[0,1]]$$

I took the partial derivatives and got:

$$\frac{df}{dx} = \cos(xy)y \text{   ... and ...   } \frac{df}{dy} = \cos(xy)y$$

I each of them equal to zero and found one critical point (0,0).

I then found the value of $\sin(xy)$ at each of the corner points of the domain.

$f(0,1) = 0, f(0,0) = 0, f(\pi,1) = 0, f(\pi,0) = 0$

Then I found equations for each of the sides of the domain box:

Right side $x = \pi$ so $\sin(\pi y)$

Top $y = 1$ so $\sin(x)$

Left side $x=0$ so $\sin(0)$

Bottom $y=0$ so $\sin(0)$

I took the $\frac{df}{dy}$ of the right and top, set them equal to zero and got:

Right > $\cos(\pi y)\pi = 0$ when $y=\frac{1}{2}$

Top > $\cos(x)=0$ when $x=0$

I plugged $(\pi, \frac{1}{2})$ and $(0,1)$ into $\sin(xy)$ and I got:
$$\sin(xy) = 1 \text{ for } (\pi,\frac{1}{2})$$
$$\sin(xy) = 0 \text{ for } (0,1)$$

Am I going about this correctly?

Anyone?

Screenshot
[image]

Comment: Still need help with this one please!

Comment: Did you mean to write $D=\{(x,y); x\in [0,1], y\in [0,1]\}$ instead of 
$D=[(x,y)| x = [0,\pi], y=[0,1]]$?

Comment: No, the problem does say x = [0,$\pi$]

Comment: Well that does not make much sense. (Perhaps it is a typo?) The equation $x=[0,\pi]$ says that a number is equal to interval. Where is this problem from? (Which book/lecture notes/assignment...?)

Comment: Its from an exam review. I posted a screenshot of it in my original question. I may have written it wrong when I transferred it over.

Answer (score 1):

$xy$ on your set $D$ take all and only values from $[0,\pi]$. So, as $\sin(t)$ has for image $[0,1]$ when $t \in [0,\pi]$, you can conclude easily.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Sorry, this isn't a easy thing for me to grasp. Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: @z400jt What Arnaud means it shit. You have $0\le x\le\pi$ and $0\le y\le1$, therefore $0\le xy \le \pi$. So if you take $x,y\in D$, you have $f(xy)=\sin t$ for some $t\in[0,\pi]$. Therefore $f(x,y)$ can only attain values from the interval $[0,1]$. (These are the values which sine attains on the interval $[0,1]$.) Now it suffice if you can find $(x,y)\in D$ such that $f(x,y)=0$ and $(x,y)\in D$ such that $f(x,y)=1$ and you know that minimal value is $0$ and maximal value if $1$.

Comment: In the preceding comment I somehow typed "it shit" instead of (intended) "is this". Sorry for the typo (which might seem rather impolite. However, I cannot edit the comment now.)